# TFS unresolvable conflict?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, checkin

(Using Visual Studio Professional 2015)

I'm am trying to check in a *.js to our TFS.
The "Resolve conflict" windows shows this file as conflict and offers me only two choices "Take Server Version" and "Keep Local Version".

What I would like to do is "Keep Local Version".

If I click "**Keep Local Version**", I get

> Error One or more warnings occurred while resolving. Full information
>   on these warnings is available in the Output Window.

In Output Window:

> The item [My item] already has pending changes.

If I click "**Keep Server Version**", I get 
The file is deleted from my local environment.
(I checked and at this point, this file doesn't exist on TFS nor in my local environment.
Then recreate it, I get back at the starting point of this question.

This happens since some time ago, on of my colleagues moved a lot files/folders into a subfolder. But all conflicts/problems have been solved since then. Only this files keep causing problem.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: How can I know this ? (without be TFS admin?)

Answer (score 1):

TFS uses the path of the file as its unique identifier. There are sometimes issues that arise with this, particularly if files are moved in a different branch. Try deleting the file, submitting that change, then re-adding it. Or try adding the file with a different name, and renaming it later.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both but still cycling on the same issue.

Comment: Can you just check in the file with a new name and not rename it to the old name?

Comment: I tried it but it gets me back to my starting point (unresolvable conflict).

Comment: It's solved. There was an additional version of the file (written by TFS when trying to resolve conflict). That appear like it was occupying two names. I got the latest version for this file, deleted it, recreated my file and it finally worked.

Comment: @TTT You could post the solution as an answer, then accept it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of that, I usually do it. But it came after so many manipulations and try that I cannot recreate the conditions that created the probable and I feel that my explanation is a bit too vague to make it an answer.